# ToolTip causes cross thread operation?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Help me understand this. I'm debugging some old code. Anyway I have this method:

```
    private void textBox1_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        toolTip1.SetToolTip(textBox1, "This is a test tooltip");
        toolTip1.Show("This is a test tooltip", this, label3.Location, 2000);
    }
```

This method works as expected, it shows a tooltip right after successful validation. This all happens on a child form in a MDI application. If I try to close the form afterwards (doesn't matter if tooltop is visible or not) I get this error:

> Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'TestForm' accessed from a
>   thread other than the thread it was created on    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_Handle()    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.SetParentHandle(IntPtr value)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection.Remove(Control value)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.MdiClient.ControlCollection.Remove(Control
>   value)    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.Dispose(Boolean disposing)    at
>   VlastitiBackgroundWorker.BazniEkran.Dispose(Boolean disposing) in
>   D:\TFSWorkspace\VlastitiBackgroundWorker\VlastitiBackgroundWorker\BazniEkran.Designer.cs:line
>   20    at VlastitiBackgroundWorker.DesetSekundi.Dispose(Boolean
>   disposing) in
>   D:\TFSWorkspace\VlastitiBackgroundWorker\VlastitiBackgroundWorker\DesetSekundi.Designer.cs:line
>   20    at System.ComponentModel.Component.Dispose()    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmClose(Message& m)

Why? It's reproducible.

Comment: Are you sure it's this code?

Comment: when is `textBox1_Validated` called?

Comment: May be you try to access your control from BackgroundWorker

Comment: It seems your Background Worker component is accessing your TestForm (this) instance.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. If I comment out these two lines of code I won't get this error. Validated method is called from Validated event. The project doesn't contain any multithreaded operations.

Comment: I know the name is misleading but VlastitiBackgroundWorker is a project name where I do my tests. Sorry about that.

Comment: Why do you think the Validated handler relates to the error? Anyway it looks suspicious that a BackgroundWorker is disposing of a Form (VlastitiBackgroundWorker.BazniEkran.Dispose).

Comment: There is no BackgroundWorker, just an unfortunately named project.

Comment: Maybe your project is so unfortunately named that it spontaneously created a BackgroundWorker?  :-)

Comment: Yeah, be careful what you wish for... :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
private void textBox1_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                toolTip1.SetToolTip(textBox1, "This is a test tooltip");
                toolTip1.Show("This is a test tooltip", this, label3.Location, 2000);
            });
        }
```

Comment: Are you create toolTip1 in a separate thread? Try to use toolTip1.Invoke() method, it will run on toolYip1 created thread

Answer (score 1):

Upon further investigation I have found that if I disable the TabbedMDIManager third party component from Syncfusion that this error goes away. I use this component to make my MDI child forms look like tabs just like VisualStudio does.

Now I have no idea what is the connection here between that component and this event method but It's obvious I need to do more investigation and probably contact Syncfusion support.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You should have included the information in the first paragraph in your question. Third party components change the equation significantly.

Comment: I disagree. Software uses third party components all the time, and stackoverflow would become untenable to use if every time someone had a problem they listed all the third party libraries they were using

Answer (score 0):

```
//Use Invoke or BeginInvoke on the control itself for cross threading manipulation..

            private void textBox1_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                toolTip1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                {
                    toolTip1.SetToolTip(textBox1, "This is a test tooltip");
                    toolTip1.Show("This is a test tooltip", this, label3.Location, 2000);
                });
            }
```